# Synonymise tags [osx-el-capitan] & [osx-10.11]

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

I just created these 2 tags.
Could someone please synonymise them for me, I don't have the rep to do it.

Also:

```
 [osx-10.7] and [osx-lion] 
 [osx-10.6] and [osx-snow-leopard]
 [osx-10.5] and [osx-leopard]
```

To be thorough, we really ought to have these tags & synonyms too
(names exist already, numbers don't.)

[osx-10.8] -> [osx-mountain-lion]
[osx-10.9] -> [osx-mavericks]
[osx-10.10] -> [osx-yosemite]

Edit3 - I'm learning as I go here, sorry.
I figured out how I can edit synonyms, but El Capitan > 10.11 doesn't have enough usage for me to do it.
The others fail because they don't yet exist.

To make matters worse - https://superuser.com/posts/391155/revisions shows an incorrect edit in progress - tag is mountain-lion, edit refers to Yosemite.

Comment: I added 10.5, 6, and 7 for synonomizing, but it looks like they might already be.  The excerpts are different but the question counts match.

Comment: Looks like they already are in http://superuser.com/tags - but 8, 9 & 10 are missing altogether

Comment: Anybody know if there's a way to clone a tag for a ready-made wiki, or do we need to create three new tags and manually copy the wikis?

Comment: I already proposed an edit to fix Mountain Lion.  It appears to have been previously used as a template for Yosemite and got incorrectly changed.  There's actually two edits.  The first, I tried to clean up what was there and later realized the entire thing was wrong so I submitted the second.

Comment: I don't see them in the queue - ahh, that might be a rep thing again, I forget I've less than 5k in here

Comment: Dumb question: OS X 10.5 through 10.7 apparently had their own questions as well as did the "name" tags.  Somehow, we managed to get here with no number tags for 10.8 through 10.10.  10.11 is about to be released, so new questions on older versions will dwindle.  If there are no questions for 10.8-10.10, why do we need tags?  We would have to post redundant tags on some questions just to keep them in existence.  Maybe just skip the missing number tags (could even remove the 10.11 tag)?

Comment: Maybe it's just me.... my OCD tells me we need synonymised tags for all OSes ;)